# Multivariate multiple regression in R with mice

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, multivariate-regression, mice

I have imputed a data set with mice and want to run a multivariate multiple linear regression on the imputed data. Below is a description of what I have done.

```
# Imputing data
imp<-mice(df, m=25, maxit=100, seed=1234, meth=initial1$method, 
             pred=initial1$predictorMatrix)

# Running model
fit<-with(imp, lm(cbind(dv1,dv2)+iv3+iv4+iv5))

# Pooling results
res<-pool(fit)
```

However, when trying to pool the results, I get this error code:

```
Error in glance.mlm(X[[i]], ...) : 
  glance does not support multiple responses
```

Any suggestions about how to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to apply Rubin's rules directly to the results of the multivariate regressions on each of the imputed data sets. You average the coefficient matrices (from `coef()` on each model) to get the pooled estimates of the coefficients, calculate variance among the individual coefficient matrices to get the between-imputation variance, and then average the coefficient covariance matrices (from `vcov()` on each model) to get the within-imputation variance estimates.

[Marshall et al](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-9-57) show formulas (in Table 2) for significance testing once those matrices are prepared from the individual regressions.

Answer (score 1):

Entered a plus instead of a tilde. Here is the correct code:

```
imp <- mice(df, m=25, maxit=100, seed=1234, meth=initial1method,
            pred=initial1predictorMatrix)

fit <- with(imp, lm(cbind(dv1,dv2)~iv3+iv4+iv5))

res <- pool(fit)
```